# How will I start this proof? (A set being open)

Tags: general-topology

Show that:
$\left\{{p :  |p-p_o|>r}\right\}$ is open for any $p_o$ and any $r\geq0$.

How will I start this proof? What should I need to show i.e should a delta neighborhood needed? If so, how should I use it?

Comment: Who is the space $X$? Which topology are you consider on $X$?

Answer (score 0):

Fix $r$ and $p_0$

Show that every point in your set is an inner point by finding a neighborhood that is contained in your point.

To find such a neighborhood remember that a metric satisfies the triangle inequality. Rearrange it to get a sufficient condition such that points in the neighborhood remain in your set.

I hope I haven't given away too much.

Comment: Since this is your first answer here, I thought I'd point you to a useful link on [how to format math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you! The link is very useful. Does it make a difference that I am on the mobile version? The subscript does not render.

Comment: I don't think it should make a difference but I'm not sure. Are you sure you typed \$p_0\$ ?

Comment: You got it working now.

Comment: @wltrup That fixed it. So its basically the same as Latex. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. As far as I know or care, MathJax is just LaTeX without the document formatting options. Occasionally you run into formatting issues but, generally, if you know LaTeX, you know MathJax.